# How to join information from two table to one

Tags: r

I am very newbie with R. I have two table as follow (data frame)

```
ID    running_time
1     10
1     2
2     1
2     3
2     4
```

And another table as

```
ID    age
1     20
1     NA
2     30
2     NA
2     NA
```

I would like to extract information for age from table 2 and fullfill each column in table 1. My expected output is

```
ID    running_time   age 
1     10             20
1     2              20
2     1              30
2     3              30
2     4              30
```

How could I do it in R? Thanks

Comment: Try: `left_join(df1, df2 %>% na.omit(), by = 'ID')
`?

Comment: Thanks I will close the question. Could I ask a small question releate to the data above. How to assign group/class for table 1 with condition >25==> group 1 and <25 group 2?